# Fetch key, value from a JSON into a new array

Tags: angularjs

I need an array of values to be created from a JSON.
I am trying to achieve it using angular.forEach, sample plunk http://next.plnkr.co/edit/eXQ1gqO2DXzQKxFY which seems to not work!
Please let me know whats incorrect or if there is any better method to achieve this.
For example:

```
// Sample JSON
$scope.Data = {"Gate": [{"Entry": "One"},{"Entry": "Two"}]};
$scope.results = [];
$scope.results = ["One","Two"];
```

I need the results array.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let Data = {"Gate": [{"Entry": "One"},{"Entry": "Two"}]};
let results = Data.Gate.map(v => v.Entry);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: I made it work in the long way like this http://next.plnkr.co/edit/eXQ1gqO2DXzQKxFY
Thanks Nikhil, the map function seems awesome. I am getting an error that tells 'map is not a function'. Are there any pre-requisites to use this?
My app runs on Angular JS 1.3

Thanks!

Comment: @SruthiEmmidi - It works fine for me. See the updated plunker - http://next.plnkr.co/edit/u1lD3XpQbRKkKwli

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` was added in ECMAScript 5.1, if the browser you are using doesn't currently support it, then you would get the `"map is not a function"` error. If you look at the link included on the answer, there is a "browser compatibility" section near the bottom.